# Read a letsencrypt cert with Node.js

Tags: node.js, certificate, fs, lets-encrypt

What might cause this? I list two certificate files in ~/TC/bin and I see them.

```
~/TC/bin$ ls
cert.pem  key.pem
```

I try to read those files from ~/TC/server.js

```
var credentials = {
  key:  fs.readFileSync('bin/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('bin/cert.pem')
};
```

I get an error message saying they're not found. I suspect it may be caused by file permissions though I'm not certain how to appropriately adjust it for something like a secure key asset.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'bin/key.pem'
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're not providing slash at the begining you're telling node that he should look for node module (npm). Try with ./ as a start. So './bin/key.pem'

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I get the same message after the change.

Comment: check permissions to file then